# Get latest user comments from posts sql

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I`m new to sql.I have two joined tables, it's posts tables posts and comments, I'm using MySql.

```
Post :

id, UserName, Phone , product

Comments:

id , CommentText, post_id
```

I'm ussing join query to join them

```
SELECT  t1.UserName , t1.Phone, t2.Comments
FROM table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON (t1.id = t2.follow_id )
```

And now I need to display all unique users and their last comments,so they look like that

```
1. User1  LastComment1
2. User2  LastComment2
3. User3  LastComment3
...
```

I will be very grateful for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i assume that column id in both tables are AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY.

This corelated subquery wil give you the correct answer.

**Query**

```
SELECT
   Post.Username
 , Post.Phone
 , (SELECT 
     Comments.CommentText
    FROM 
     Comments
    WHERE
     Comments.post_id = Post.id
    ORDER BY 
     Comments.id DESC
    LIMIT 1
   ) 
    AS LastComment
FROM 
 Post
```

You might want to add a index on the Comments.post_id to improve performance off this query.

Comment: Thanks,you are my savior!That is what I needed.